# Dynamic SQL Error (.NET-Firebird-Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I execute my solution on Visual Studio I got this error in my controller `ProductoController.cs`

[image]

However, if I continue with the debugging of the solution (avoiding the same error at least 3 times) I can display the content of my table of my DB.

I'm using a DB from FirebirdSQL. I checked my query, my models and controllers. I checked in my project if I had the element _MigrationHistory (the Unknown Table?), but not.

In my model `ModelController.cs` I have this:

```
namespace ConsultasEjecutivas.Models
{
    public class SAEContext : DbContext
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; }

        public SAEContext(string connectionString, string tableName)
            : base(new FbConnection(connectionString), true)
        {
            this.TableName = tableName;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            var monDatabaseConfiguration = modelBuilder.Entity<Producto>();
            monDatabaseConfiguration.HasKey(x => x.ClaveArticulo);
            monDatabaseConfiguration.Property(x => x.ClaveArticulo).HasColumnName("CVE_ART");
            monDatabaseConfiguration.Property(x => x.Descripcion).HasColumnName("DESCR");
            monDatabaseConfiguration.Property(x => x.LineaProducto).HasColumnName("LIN_PROD");
            monDatabaseConfiguration.Property(x => x.UltimoCosto).HasColumnName("ULT_COSTO");
            monDatabaseConfiguration.ToTable(TableName);
        }

        public DbSet<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my ProductoController.cs is this:

```
namespace ConsultasEjecutivas.Controllers
{
    public class ProductoController : Controller
    {
        string connectionString;
        string tableName;
        private SAEContext db;

        public ProductoController()
        {            
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConecctionString"];
            tableName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TableName"];
            db = new SAEContext(connectionString, tableName);
        } 

        // GET: Test
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var query = from p in db.Productos
                        select p; // error?

            return View(query);
        }
    }
}
```

And Producto.cs looks like this:

```
namespace ConsultasEjecutivas.Models
{
    public class Producto
    {
            public string ClaveArticulo { get; set; }
            public string Descripcion { get; set; }
            public string LineaProducto { get; set; }
            public decimal UltimoCosto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'll appreciate any help to solve my problem.

Comment: Put the complete error.

Comment: how are you avoiding the issue 3 times as you put it.. are you just stepping over to the next line..?

Comment: @MethodMan Only I click to "Continuar" debugging

Comment: @Dnyanesh 
* FIrst time: `{"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -204\r\nTable unknown\r\n__MigrationHistory\r\nAt line 7, column 29"}`
* Second time: `{"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -204\r\nTable unknown\r\n__MigrationHistory\r\nAt line 7, column 29"}`
* Third time: `{"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -204\r\nTable unknown\r\nEdmMetadata\r\nAt line 5, column 19"}`

Comment: Go to Debug->Exceptions and uncheck Common Language Runtime Exceptions in the "Break when an exception is thrown" column. EF is probing for migrations history table and is catching the exception however because you have the checkbox checked VS breaks on the exception.

Comment: @Pawel And unchecked the Common Language Runtime Exceptions will solve my problem or only avoid it?

Comment: There is no problem. This is the expected behavior. EF is checking if the table exists and this operation throws if the table does not exist. Then EF catches this exception and handles it so it does not get back to you. You only see it when debugging because you opted in to see all the exceptions when they are thrown **even if** they are handled. Unchecking the checkbox will hide handled exceptions. Unhandled exceptions will still cause the debugger to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Debug->Exceptions and uncheck Common Language Runtime Exceptions in the "Break when an exception is thrown" column. EF is probing for migrations history table and is catching the exception however because you have the checkbox checked VS breaks on the exception.

Comment: Uhmm, my solution was executed with success, but for example: If I create a new solution, and have it errors but I can't see it because I unchecked the Common Language Runtime Exceptions, this change doesn't affect my new projects? For example, executing a new solution that displays the solution of my problem but it have errors. 

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Again, this only turns off breaking on exceptions where they are thrown and not unhandled exceptions. In the vast majority of cases you should not care if an exception was thrown if it was handled before it reached your code. The debugger will break on the exceptions that reach your code. Note that this checkbox is unchecked by default. What was the reason you checked it? Did it help? Do you know if it even made a difference?

Comment: It was selected by default during the installation.